# jQuery datepicker immediately change Year/Month

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

How I can change year/month immediately in text input? I've enabled Year and Month dropdowns by options "changeYear" and "changeMonth", but when I am selecting another Year in dropdown box, my text input showing date does not shows new Year.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you post a [JSFiddle](http://www.JSFiddle.net) of your HTML and Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. This code makes exactly I need.

```
jQuery('.ed_ui-datepicker').datepicker({
    'changeMonth': true,
    'changeYear': true,
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst){
        var currentDate = jQuery(this).datepicker( "getDate" );
        jQuery(this).datepicker( "setDate", new Date(year, month-1, currentDate.getDate()) );
    }
});
```